# Why when Restore In App purchase, My app crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

When I press Restore IAP my app crashed,
I use test account,what is the problem, maybe you know

method for restore transaction:

```
- (void) restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{   
    [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] provideContent: transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier]; 
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction]; 
}
```

[image]